# "Learn SQL The Hard Way" - How to Setup Properly for Beginner?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, sqlite

I am a *beginner* attempting to learn SQL with **Zed Shaw's** ["How to Learn SQL the Hard Way"](http://sql.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex0.html)

***In excercise 0: The Set up***, he states:

*Then, look to see that the test.db file is there. If that works then you're all set.*

But when I run the command,

sqlite> create table test (id);

 sqlite> .quit

the execution runs, but **it doesn't create a test.db file**. I looked in the **same folder as where the sqlite3.exe file** is and I see nothing.

I attempt to see if I can **continue without this step**, then - In his next exercise, "Excercise 1: Creating Tables":

I input his commands, but when attempting to run **sqlite3 ex1.db < ex1.sql**, it gives me an error.

I even tried putting the create table command and saving it as a '.sql' file into the same folder as sqlite3.exe.

How can I set this environment up **properly**? Can someone explain this on an "easy to grasp" level? Any response is appreciated**

---

### Edit 1

I'm not exactly sure how Zed Shaw how he wants his learners to use SQLite 3, Maybe I can go into some research but I just don't understand why he leaves such a large gap of assumption that everyone knows what to do for the set up process...

Comment: Show exactly your commands and the output when you tried exercise 0.

Comment: If you haven't seen it before, I'd recommend w3schools for a much quicker and easier bit of self-tuition. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_intro.asp

Comment: I've already gone through the entire W3Schools SQL tutorial and Aced the QUIZ. To be honest I'm better at learning when I'm actually performing tasks, so this is why I chose Zed Shaw's book as the next step.

Comment: Works for me. There are things you could mistype or leave out that could cause your symptoms.

Comment: Define, 'Works for me'.

Comment: Copy and paste the 3 commands from exercise 0, and the file is created. Isn't that what you were hoping would happen?

Comment: Oh, I see now that you're on Windows. Some of those command line commands you will need to "translate". But the first one from exercise 0 should be no problem to type correctly.

Comment: so what is test.db into a workable command in windows?

Comment: The commands executes, but nothing happens I do the command.

Comment: Are you running the create db command?  I don't see that in your post.  Start here for a simple intro:  [Clicky!](http://www.sqlite.org/quickstart.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem. I am using windows 7. 
From this website: http://www.sqlite.org/download.html
I used the: 
"sqlite-tools-win32-x86-3130000.zip
(1.51 MiB)      A bundle of command-line tools for managing SQLite..."
under the **"Precompiled Binaries for Windows"** heading. 
My helper directed me to open the file named "sqlite3" after I'd extracted the files from the zip file. 
It brought up a black window, in the command line style, showing some text, and then the familiar **sqlite>** prompt.
Then he had me input:"  .save data_base_name.db  "  (I chose to have my database be named 'thedatabase'.)
which created a file in the same folder as the sqlite3 file, called "data_base_name" as a "Data Base File". 
That's where I'm at so far, I'll post updates as I have them.

Comment: Please check this [URL](http://stackoverflow.com/help) it will be useful to lift you content quality up